# .NET Core : could not find the path of the data

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API project. It's a single layer project but I need to change it to three layers so I created a business and a data access layer as two separate projects, and added references to the main project.

I am just doing some CRUD operation in a Json file. After moving the JSON file to data access layer project, I get this error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\BRIDGEON\Dot Net Core Web Api\JsonApi\JsonAPI\JsonAPI\DataAcessLayer\Data\datas.json'.

appsettings.json:

```
"AppSettings": 
{
    "JsonFilePath": "DataAcessLayer/Data/datas.json"
}
```

Comment: Compare the path to the actual file path to the letter. Chances are, it's incorrect.

Comment: DataAcessLayer is my new project name and the json file is located in Data folder so I think the path is correct

Answer (score 0):

From your error message,it seems your startup Project share the same name with Solution Name: `JsonAPI`

Generate the path like:

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "DataAcessLayer","Data","data.json");
```

[image]

In C#,if your startup project call another project which call `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` ,you would get the path of startup project

It would work when you debug:

```
var currentpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
DirectoryInfo pathinfo=new DirectoryInfo(currentpath);
var newpath = pathinfo.Parent.FullName;
string path = Path.Combine(newpath, "DataAcessLayer","Data","data.json");
```

[image]

[image]